# In win32 api using c++ i want to track double click and triple click and so on

Tags: c++, winapi, mouseevent

```
LRESULT handleDoubleClicks(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, POINT ptLastClickPos, DWORD dwLastClickTime)
{
    DWORD dwClickTime = GetMessageTime();
    POINT ptClickPos = { GET_X_LPARAM(lParam), GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam) };
    switch(message)
    {
    case  WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
        if (dwLastClickTime + GetDoubleClickTime() > dwClickTime
            && abs(ptLastClickPos.x - ptClickPos.x) < GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXDOUBLECLK)
            && abs(ptLastClickPos.y - ptClickPos.y) < GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYDOUBLECLK))
        {
            MessageBox(hWnd, TEXT("Double click"), TEXT("I appear when double clicked"), MB_OKCANCEL);

        }
        else
        {
            dwLastClickTime = dwClickTime;
            ptLastClickPos = ptClickPos;
            wchar_t waCoord[20];
            wsprintf(waCoord, _T("(%i,%i)"), ptLastClickPos.x, ptLastClickPos.y);
            MessageBox(hWnd, waCoord, _T("Left mouse button click"), MB_OK);
        }
        break;
     default:
         return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
}
```

This is function i have made to handle double click:
This function is called when windows recieve `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` it will take the time of the message and coordinate of the click and will transfer it to the function here i want the fuction to recieve another message `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` and determine the time of the message and compare with the previous click time and the co ordinates to identify if it is a double click.
But this is not working .May be I am Wrong with the approach I am newbie Pls help me to solve this problem.

```
 case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
   {
        dwLastClickTime= GetMessageTime();
        // SetTimer(hWnd,0,GetDoubleClickTime(),0);
        ptLastClickPos.x = LOWORD(lParam);
        ptLastClickPos.y = HIWORD(lParam);
        handleDoubleClicks(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam, ptLastClickPos, dwLastClickTime);

   }
```

Comment: Please read [ask] with a [mcve]

Comment: @RichardCritten I have edited question please do answer

Comment: @DrakeWu-MSFT i want to use single clicks also in my project along with double click that is why I am not using `WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK`

Comment: [Implementing higher-order clicks](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20041018-00/?p=37543).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`SetTimer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-settimer), after one click, not immediately judge it as a click, but start the timer, check whether there is another click within the timer range, if there is, it is judged as double-click, if not, and the previous time is determined as a single click.

```
#define TIMER_ID 10
static int click_count = 0;
static POINT point = { 0 };
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_TIMER:
    {
        KillTimer(hWnd, TIMER_ID);
        if (click_count == 1)
        {
            wchar_t waCoord[20];
            wsprintf(waCoord, _T("(%i,%i)"), point.x, point.y);
            MessageBox(hWnd, waCoord, _T("Left mouse button click"), MB_OK);
        }
        else if(click_count == 2)
        {
            MessageBox(hWnd, TEXT("Double click"), TEXT("I appear when double clicked"), MB_OKCANCEL);
        }
        else if (click_count == 3)
        {
            MessageBox(hWnd, TEXT("Triple click"), TEXT("I appear when triple clicked"), MB_OKCANCEL);
        }
        click_count = 0;
        return 0;
    }
    break;
    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
    {
        if (click_count == 0)
        {
            SetTimer(hWnd, TIMER_ID, GetDoubleClickTime(), NULL);
        }
        click_count++;
        return 0;
    }
    break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            // TODO: Add any drawing code that uses hdc here...
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And make sure your window doesn't have `CS_DBLCLKS` style. Otherwise, the second `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` message that would normally be generated becomes a `WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK` message, according to the document: [Double Clicks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/mouse-clicks#double-clicks)

Comment: now If i am trying to print coordinates they are always (0,0)

Comment: `lParam` of message `WM_TIMER` is "*A pointer to an application-defined callback function that was passed to the SetTimer function when the timer was installed*"(we set it to NULL). For the coordinates, you could also define a static POINT, and set it when you get `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`;