# Only One of the pop up is Handled?

Tags: c++, winapi

I am using `win32` API to develop an Application.I am using `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` message to handle two operation .

If a click on `button X` I want to perform operation  `A`.

a)If a double click occur on `button X` I want to perform operation `C` as well 
    that is operation `A` 
    followed by operation `C`.

But while implementing I can either perform operation `A`or operation `C`.

```
 case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
   {
       overallClicks++;
       left1.x = LOWORD(lParam);
       left1.y = HIWORD(lParam);
       wsprintf(waCoord, _T("my coordinates are (%i,%i)"), left1.x, left1.y);
      if (click_count == 0)
       {
           SetTimer(hWnd, TIMER_ID, GetDoubleClickTime(), NULL);
       }
       click_count++;
       if (fun()) {
           //do something
       }
       else {
           MessageBox(NULL, _T("yo"), _T("yo"), MB_OK);
       }
       return 0;
        // dwLastClickTime= GetMessageTime();
         //SetTimer(hWnd,0,GetDoubleClickTime(),0);
         //break;

        // handleDoubleClicks(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam, ptLastClickPos, dwLastClickTime);

   }


case WM_TIMER:
    {
        HandleTimer(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }



LRESULT HandleTimer(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    BOOL i = KillTimer(hWnd, TIMER_ID);
    if (click_count == 1)
    {
      //  wchar_t* ptr = ;
        MessageBox(hWnd, waCoord, _T("Left mouse button click"), MB_OK);
    }
    else if (click_count == 2)
    {
        MessageBox(hWnd, waCoord, TEXT("I appear when double clicked"), MB_OKCANCEL);
    }
    else if (click_count == 3)
    {
        MessageBox(hWnd, waCoord, TEXT("I appear when triple clicked"), MB_OKCANCEL);
    }
    else if (click_count > 3) {

        MessageBox(hWnd, waCoord, TEXT("I appear when rage clicked"), MB_OKCANCEL);

    }
    click_count = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

I would like elaborate for example I am double clicking on disabled button I want to show pop up that I have double clicked as well as that button is disabled.

Comment: How do you judge the mouse double click? Have you used `WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK `?

Comment: no in same `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` message using `SetTimer` and then using DoubleClickTime()` as threshold

Comment: @StriveSun-MSFT I edited the question

Comment: CS_DBLCLKS is disabled i am identifying double click using `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`

Comment: Can you tell me the reason why WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK is not used?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215637/discussion-between-strive-sun-msft-and-nurav).

Comment: A disabled window does not receive user input. We used to have a close-reason to be used when a user asking a question demonstrated complete lack of even basic familiarity with the problem domain. Sadly, that close reason is no longer.

Comment: @IInspectable I think question is clear I was just trying to give an example !

Comment: If the question is literally asking for what you need, why have you accepted an answer that doesn't provide an answer?

Comment: @IInspectable Can you solve it?

Comment: @Nurav Because the mouse event of the button is disabled, you can monitor the mouse event in the parent window. If the mouse is above the button, double-click to perform operation C. See my updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of an answer from your [previous case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61745915/11128312).

Because your code logic uses `if...else...` conditional statements. The way I can think of is to add an additional timer in the case of double-click to complete the action when clicked.

```
void CALLBACK f(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, UINT timerId, DWORD dwTime)
{
    EnableWindow(hwndButton, 0);
}
...

LRESULT CALLBACK OwnerDrawButtonProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam,
    LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_TIMER:
    {
        KillTimer(hWnd, TIMER_ID);
        if (click_count == 1)
        {
            wchar_t waCoord[20];
            wsprintf(waCoord, _T("(%i,%i)"), point.x, point.y);
            MessageBox(hWnd, waCoord, _T("Left mouse button click"), MB_OK);
            SetTimer(NULL, 0, 100, (TIMERPROC)&f);
        }
        else if (click_count == 2)
        {
            SetTimer(NULL, 0, 100, (TIMERPROC)&f);
            MessageBox(hWnd, TEXT("Double click"), TEXT("I appear when double clicked"), MB_OKCANCEL);
        }            
        click_count = 0;
        return 0;
    }
    break;
    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
    {
        if (click_count == 0)
        {
            SetTimer(hWnd, TIMER_ID, GetDoubleClickTime(), NULL);
        }
        click_count++;
        return 0;
    }
    break;

    case WM_NCDESTROY:
        RemoveWindowSubclass(hWnd, &OwnerDrawButtonProc, 1);
        break;
    }
    return DefSubclassProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Remove the `CS_DBLCLKS` style when using the button control.

**Updated:**

Because the button is disabled, I'm sorry I didn't see this. In this way, the message of the parent window can only be used to determine whether the mouse coordinates are within the range of the button. If it is, double-click to perform operation C.

Only need to modify part of the code of the parent window:

```
 LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
 {
    static RECT rc;
    static POINT pt = { 0 };
    rc.left = 10;
    rc.top = 10;
    rc.right = 110;
    rc.bottom = 110;
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        hwndButton = CreateWindow(
            L"BUTTON",  // Predefined class; Unicode assumed 
            L"OK",      // Button text 
            WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON ,  // Styles 
            10,         // x position 
            10,         // y position 
            100,        // Button width
            100,        // Button height
            hWnd,     // Parent window
            NULL,       // No menu.
            (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_HINSTANCE),
            NULL);      // Pointer not needed.
        DWORD  class_style = GetClassLongPtr(hwndButton, GCL_STYLE);
        SetClassLongPtr(hwndButton, GCL_STYLE, class_style & (~CS_DBLCLKS));

        SetWindowSubclass(hwndButton, &OwnerDrawButtonProc, IDC_OWNERDRAWBUTTON, 0);
        return TRUE;
    }
    case WM_TIMER:
    {
        KillTimer(hWnd, TIMER_ID);

        if (click_count == 2)
        {  
                MessageBox(hWnd, TEXT("Double click"), TEXT("I appear when double clicked"), MB_OKCANCEL);
        }      
        click_count = 0;
        return 0;
    }
    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
    {
        POINT p;
        p.x = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam);
        p.y = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);

        if (PtInRect(&rc, p))
        {
            pt = p;
            if (click_count == 0)
            {
                SetTimer(hWnd, TIMER_ID, GetDoubleClickTime(), NULL);
            }
            click_count++;
        }       
        return 0;
    }

    ...
```

Debug:

[image]

Comment: The OP is asking for a double-click event on a **disabled** button control. This proposed solution does not meet that requirement.